# subjunctive following insist and maintain

Tags: subjunctives

I'd like to know whether insist and maintain are both correct in the following:

John **insisted** / **maintained** that the patient **be** treated immediately.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Unlike *insist*, *maintain* isn't normally used to mean "demand", and hence only the former can be used in the described way.

Comment: Semantically, ***insist / maintain*** are pretty much equivalent in the cited context (but I expect most people would say ***insist*** is "stronger" here). Syntactically, though, I don't think the "bare infinitive / subjunctive" ***be*** really works with ***maintain*** unless you at least precede it with ***should***. To my mind, ***I insist [that] I be released*** is perfectly valid (if a little dated/formal), but ***I maintain [that] I be released*** doesn't sound much like English to me.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence with **insist** is idiomatic in American English, the one with **maintain** is not.

To **maintain** is to make an assertion of fact.  No non-actual situation  is involved with an assertion of fact. Whereas **insist** in that context is understood to be a form of demand that something should or must occur. The thing has not actually occurred, hence the subjunctive.

If **insisted** is used about a past event, rather than about something which should happen or be done, then its meaning shades into that of **maintained**.

Comment: I can certainly maintain ***that** you should do something* - it's just that I can't (syntactically? validly?, idiomatically?) ***maintain you do it***.

Comment: Merely to maintain that I should do something is not to adjure or insist that I do it. You can maintain that I should do it and still say "But do as you please".

Comment: I was talking about "idiomatic syntax", not semantics. *Jack says it's up to me to fix it, but John maintains you should fix it.* I don't think it's idiomatically valid to "delete" the word ***should*** there.

Comment: I would agree. **to maintain {something}** means **to hold the firm opinion that...** and it takes a *that*-clause whose tensed verb is not in the subjunctive, at least in my dialect.  We would not say *The cap'n maintains that ye be flogged.*